# Autorun macro in Powerpoint 2010

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I would like to auto run a macro when my PowerPoint 2010 file opens.
I hope someone would be able to assist.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article to explain how to do this [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/17410/Initializing-PowerPoint-Events-with-VBA-and-Ribbon-XML.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub App_PresentationOpen(ByVal Pres As Presentation) 
     Call yourMacro
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the above, but when I add this and replace "YourMacro" with the name it doesn't have any effect.

I also See I have a down vote. As I'm new please let me know how and what I can improve to make things clearer. Thank you.

Comment: Follow @JamieG's link instead. And if you don't need to trap events later, but simply want to fire a macro when the presentation opens, you can use onLoad="MyMacro" in the customUI section to point to your own Public Sub MyMacro.